# how to filter data in laravel with checkbox onchange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have an e-commerce site which also needs a filter option.

I have never did this before so don't know how it works. I've done some google-ing and youtube-ing and I found this code

```
<center>
    <ul>
        <a href="{{ url('category/' . $tag . '?price=100') }}"><li class="mydes2">Below $100</li></a>
        <a href="{{ url('category/' . $tag . '?price=250') }}"><li class="mydes2">Below  $250</li></a>
        <a href="{{ url('category/' . $tag . '?price=500') }}"><li class="mydes2">Below $500</li></a>
        <a href="{{ url('category/' . $tag . '?price=1000') }}"><li class="mydes2">Below $1000</li></a>
        <a href="{{ url('category/' . $tag . '?price=1500') }}"><li class="mydes2">Below $1500</li></a>
        <a href="{{ url('category/' . $tag . '?price=1500') }}"><li class="mydes2">Above $1500</li></a>
    </ul>                  
</center>
```

here is my controller

```
public function swimcategory(Request $request, $tags) {
  if(request()->has('gender')||request()->has('price')||request()->has('color')||request()->has('brand')) {
      if (request()->has('gender')) {
          $products = product::where('gender', request('gender'))->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($tags) {
              $query->where('name', $tags);
          })->get();
      }
      if (request()->has('price')) {
          $products = product::where('price', '<=', request('price'))->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($tags) {
              $query->where('name', $tags);
          })->get();
      }
      if (request()->has('color')) {
          $products = product::whereHas('colors', function ($query) {
              $query->where('name', request('color'));
          })->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($tags) {
              $query->where('name', $tags);
          })->get();
      }
      if (request()->has('brand')) {
          $products = product::whereHas('brands', function ($query) {
              $query->where('name', request('brand'));
          })->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($tags) {
              $query->where('name', $tags);
          })->get();
      }
  } else {
      $products = product::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($tags) {
          $query->where('name', $tags);
      })->get();
  }  


  $tag = $tags;
  $colors = color::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
  $brands = brand::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
  return view('category.index', compact('products', 'colors', 'brands', 'tag'));
}
```

and it work fine but I don't need an href link.

I want to add checkbox when user checks that filter, which works the same as Flipkart or Amazon site.

Comment: are you filtering a search?

Comment: no i am filtering products as categorywise

Comment: so when the user ticks the filter it would relaod applying the filter

Comment: product has many colors has one brand has one price & has one gender

Comment: so the user would select all these? is it in a form?

Comment: currently its just a link and i want to change in to form with checkbox filter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153656/discussion-between-norris-oduro-and-sid-heart).

Answer (score 0):

Done by Norris Oduro with the help of javascript 
Here is the code:

```
<script>
    function checkBoxHandler() {
        $('#color_form').submit();
    }

    $("#ex2").slider({});
</script>
```